# JAVA 8 : Change value inside stream

Tags: java, list, foreach, java-stream

I have a list of objects and I loop on every element of this list and I modify several attributes.

Here is my code that I want to transform to use the stream API.

```
        for (Besoin besoin : besoins) {
        String purchaseOrderPosition = besoin.getReferenceOa().trim();
        if(purchaseOrderPosition != "") {
            ValeursDynamiques valeursDynamiques = valeursDynamiquesService.DynamicValues(supplierNumber, purchaseOrderPosition);
            besoin.setQuantityInTransit(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteEnTransit());
            besoin.setQuantityOrdered(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteCommandee());
            besoin.setQuantityDelivered(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteRecue());
            besoin.setDeliveryDateScheduled(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getDateLivraisonPlanifiee());
            besoin.setDeliverydateConfirmed(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getDateLivraisonConfirmee());
            besoin.setQuantityRestExpedited(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getSoldeAExpedier());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Why do need to transform this code into a stream anyway? I don't think that there would be any benefit to this.

Comment: You mean [something like this](https://ideone.com/1QhIyy), be careful Strings should be compared by `.equals` not `==`

Comment: I'd argue, that if you have to perform that many operations on an instance, a stream is less legible. Furthermore, streams can't/shouldn't mutate the source, so in this case you will have to create a new list. Looking at @YCF_L's code, you will end up with a copy of the list, but only containing the filtered elements. So if you actually do need all of them, or need to mutate the source, I'd stick with the classic loop.

Comment: This is a good and thorough introduction to streams: https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment: @YCF_L Thank you for your answer but what's the difference between .equals (...) and isEmpty?

Comment: @CHARAFISaad comparing a String with `""` is equivalent to `isEmpty()` no difference

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017223/1059372

Comment: Is `besoins` a list, some other collection, an array, …? If a collection you may consider `besoins.forEach` rather than a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be corrrect since you aren't modifiying the list but the attribut of the element :

```
    besoins.stream().forEach(besoin -> {
    String purchaseOrderPosition = besoin.getReferenceOa().trim();
    if(!purchaseOrderPosition.isEmpty()) {
        ValeursDynamiques valeursDynamiques = valeursDynamiquesService.DynamicValues(supplierNumber, purchaseOrderPosition);
        besoin.setQuantityInTransit(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteEnTransit());
        besoin.setQuantityOrdered(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteCommandee());
        besoin.setQuantityDelivered(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getQteRecue());
        besoin.setDeliveryDateScheduled(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getDateLivraisonPlanifiee());
        besoin.setDeliverydateConfirmed(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getDateLivraisonConfirmee());
        besoin.setQuantityRestExpedited(valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues().getSoldeAExpedier());
    }   
}
```

you can directly use `forEach()` from list, and I have use the `isEmpty()` intead of `!= ""`.

But as previously stated why use a Stream here ? `besoins.stream().forEach(besoin ->` is less readable than `for (Besoin besoin : besoins)`

In general when prefer stream to filter, map, and extract some data

Comment: but please when we can use stream, why we use it ? for me i want to use Stream because i use Java 8 in my project.

Comment: yes fine use stream, like in my answer. But a foreach loop is simpler to read, stream over list are used in gneral to aply filter, or map, then extract an other list or Something else...

Comment: @user43968 funny :) you wrote the answer 1/2 hour later which says *exactly* what I did...

Comment: @Eugene I can't see where you use Stream in your answer and where you transform the for loop ;) ,and for the other part I said "as previously stated"

Comment: This one is a weird mix between a loop and a stream. Assuming that boseins is a collection, even `besoins.forEach(...)`would work. I'd also recommend to extract the consumer to a method for testability: `besoins.forEach(this::foo)` and: `void foo(final Besoins value) { ... }`.

Comment: For the sake of readability, keep the result of `valeursDynamiques.getUsedValues()` in a local variable instead of calling it six times. The variable wouldn’t even raise the number of lines, as it makes the other local variable, `valeursDynamiques`, obsolete…

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the elements from the *source* of the stream is *not* a structural change of the source per-se. Yes, you can do it, even in `parallel` this will not fail. But it's hardly the point streams where made for; unless you have other operations that you might need (`filter`, `map`, etc) your loop makes a lot more sense.

For example `ArrayList` documentation says:

> ... merely setting the value of an element is not structural modification

As such your code that modifies an element, but not the source of the stream (`List` in your case) will *not* throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: but in my case the change are in the source (List) stream it's just a data pipe

Comment: @CHARAFISaad sorry i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Stream provide data from source as Collection or Array and dont modify the source. after Filters and modifications we use the collect() method to transform to new list

Comment: @CHARAFISaad ok... and your question is? I don't understand you again. Point is if you modify the `List` - that is the *source* of your stream, like adding or deleting an element of the list - this is a structural change and this will not work (`ConcurrentModificationException`); if you modify an attribute of one of the elements from that list that *is not* a structural change and your code is fine.